# PerlOutputFilterHandler module in Apache 2.4

Tags: 16.04, apache2, apache2.4

While upgrading from Apache2.2 to Apache2.4 I noticed an error in my apachectl configtest:

```
Invalid command 'PerlOutputFilterHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

As far as I know is this is simply an issue with a2enmod *apachemodule* but I can't seem to find the corresponding module and it looks like there is no such module in Apache 2.4? I have tried (according to [this link](https://lists.gt.net/modperl/modperl/108227)) disabling mod_deflate by issueing `a2dismod deflate` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2
a2enmod perl
```